# Why images of asp.net toggle button created with checkbox doesn't show inside updatepanel in webusercontrol?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Why images of asp.net toggle button created with checkbox doesn't show inside updatepanel in webusercontrol ?

Answer (score 0):

Because inside updatepanel you need to initialized it after every 'ajax' call.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    InitToggleButton();
}
```

Comment: How to use this in asp.net (vb) page ?

Comment: @Squiti This is Javascript !, you add it inside the page on javascript session, and is the same on vb -:)   Please google it, here is one link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx